# Accessing private method from a static one

Tags: flutter, dart, methods, static, private

I'm trying to access a private method from a static one in the same class in Dart.

```
class MyClass{

  void _initFunc() {
    /// ...
  }

  static void info(){
    if (condition){
      _initFunc();
    }
  }
}
```

I got this error

> Instance members can't be accessed from a static method.

Can you please explain me why, and how can i do. info() must be static, and _initFunc() must be private.

Comment: Because there is no instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "this" in a static method. So `MyClass.info()` doesn't have a "this" to call `this._initFunc();`

In Dart the static modifier on class members and methods makes them available without creating an instance of a class object. For example special constructors are `static` because you want to *create* a instance with them. Consider `MyClass foo = MyClass.fromAnotherObject(bar);` -> `static MyClass fromAnotherObject(){}` is static because you don't yet have a MyClass object to call it on.

In your example code, you could change `_initFunc()` to a public function (remove the "_") and either:

a) instantiate a MyClass object inside your static info() method and call initFunc()

```
class MyClass{

  void initFunc() {
    /// ...
  }

  static void info(){
    if (condition){
      MyClass myClass = MyClass();
      myClass.initFunc();
    }
  }
}
```

OR

b) declare initFunc() also static and call it from info()

```
class MyClass{

  static void initFunc() {
    /// ...
  }

  static void info(){
    if (condition){
      MyClass.initFunc();
    }
  }
}
```